# How to change the "This category has no blog posts yet!" text

Tags: categories

I want to change the text that appears when a category has no posts. By standard it says "This category has no blog posts yet!"

How/where do I customise that text please?

Comment: This will be in your themes code, the message isn't coming from WP itself. E.g. my site says "Not found"

Answer (score 0):

You can modify archive.php and modify loop as well as messages. Here is the reference link:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-category-templates-in-wordpress/